# call asp.net onClick method from jquery dialog button

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-dialog

Here's my admin.aspx.cs file anchor tag that passes the cID value.

```
    string l = "";
    while (dr.Read()) //sqldatareader
    {
    l += "<li class='icon-del' >";
                l += "<a id='del' runat='server' onClick='delete' href='?id=";
                l += dr["cID"].ToString();
                l += "'>";
                l += "</a>";
                l += "</li>";
     }
    lit_Category.Text = l;
```

It is then displayed on Literal in admin.aspx as

```
     <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="lit_Category" > </asp:Literal>
```

I want to confirm delete using jquery dialog as

```
    $(function () {
    $("#del-dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 300,
    height: 100,
    modal: true,
    close: function (event, ui) {
        location.reload(false);
    },
     buttons: {
         'Delete': function () {
             $("#<%=del.ClientID %>").click(); 
                $(this).dialog('close');  
        },
        'Cancel': function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});

$(".icon-del").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#del-dialog").dialog("open");
});
});
```

The 'Delete' button should call the delete() function which on my admin.aspx.cs page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the 'Delete' event function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "admin.aspx/delete?cid=1",
    success: function(data) {
        alert('deleted');
    }
});
```